# c# масштабируемый график/рисунок/контрол

Tags: c#, winforms, usercontrol

Начал рисовать один весьма странный компонент для формы и пришел к выводу что лучше если бы он был масштабируемым. Компонент предназначен в первую очередь для отрисовки некоего изображения, но не взаимодействия с ним.

Как нарисовать "векторный" рисунок который можно было бы масштабировать под ширину формы?

В какую сторону вообще копать?

Comment: svg масштабируются, а вот можно ли их применить в winforms - не уверен.

Comment: можно при помощи SVG.NET  нюгета. Но вот есть ли другой более родной путь -- вопрос...